# How to expand the string variable as html content in Angular 10?

Tags: angular

I set my variable like:

**.ts**

```
html = '<p>hi</p>'
```

and I want to use it like:

**.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="html">
  {{ html }}
</ng-container>
```

to see 'hi' so to use it as rendered html. Is there any way to do that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use innerHtml like this -

```
<div *ngIf="html" [innerHtml] = "html"></div>
```